# dApp Staking - Migration from v2 to v3

Tags: astar

Please, I need help on the Stakes topic in v2 to v3. There's a thread on the forum, but I realized I can't participate in the questions there.

Sorry, I'm new to these processes and would like to know about this topic:
"dApp Staking - Migration from v2 to v3" I have a stake in "Astar Core Contributors", I invest in the Talisman wallet. I didn't understand very well regarding the unlinking of dapp v2 to v3. What do I need to do besides claiming the reward tokens? I wanted to know, for example, if I need to unlink from the dapp or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question!

There is nothing special that you need to do before the upgrade to v3. What you should do is, once dApp Staking is upgraded to v3 is to go back to Astar Portal and choose the same or new dApps that you want to support in the voting period.

For more details please check this FAQ on the official Astar Docs https://docs.astar.network/docs/learn/dapp-staking-v3/dapp-staking-faq#general-info-about-migration-from-v2-to-v3